# Custom Plugin Database relations

Tags: plugin-development, database, wpdb

I will make custom page for my plugin.As a example, in this video, global $wpdb is used to call variables of sing-up form.How can I call my own plugin's variables? I dont know database info yet.Also can you refer a document to learn more about wordpress database relations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTNUSb_5zA8

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you refer to your plugins own variables, what do you mean? Which variables? That youtube video is 30 minutes long, if it's necessary to watch it to answer the question you need to incorporate what's needed so your question is self contained without watching a video

Comment: @TomJNowell For example, I want to provide upload video to my standart users in a custom page that is not admin panel.So I need call and fill many variables like video title,desciption etc.How can I control these variables from custom page?

Comment: @TomJNowell can I contact with you with social methods such as irc,slack or smiliar stuff?

Comment: @ExcaliburSword I've only watched about 4 minutes of the video, so could you edit your question and include some code you've tried and describe where/what you're getting stuck at/with. But the `$wpdb` is just a variable allowing you to access the WordPress database [APIs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) like `$wpdb->prepare()`, `$wpdb->insert()` and `$wpdb->update()`. And regarding the "database relations", see [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) and/or search for "WordPress database" on Google..