# is_email gives me error

Tags: functions

As you can see on this link:

https://cixme.deniz-tasarim.site/video-upload/

after click submit button, wp says me e-mail is invalid but I enter valid e-mail.

```
Array ( [email_valid] => Email has no valid value )
```

related code:

```
  if(is_email($email)) {
            $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
        }
```

full code:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Video Upload */

get_header();

    global $wpdb;

    if ($_POST) {

        $username = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtUsername']);
        $email = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtEmail']);
        $password = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtPassword']);
        $ConfPassword = $wpdb->escape($_POST['txtConfirmPassword']);

        $error = array();
        if (strpos($username, ' ')!==FALSE) {
            $error['username_space'] = "Username has Space";
        }
        if(empty($username)) {
            $error['username_empty'] = "Needed Username must";
        }
        if(username_exists($username)) {
            $error['username_exists'] = "Username already exists";
        }
        if(is_email($email)) {
            $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
        }
        if(email_exists($email)) {
            $error['email_existence'] = "Email already exists";
        }
        if (strcmp($password, $ConfPassword) !==0) {
            $error['password'] = "Password didn't match";
        }
        if (count($error) == 0) {
            wp_create_user($username,$password,$email);
            echo "User created successfully";
            exit();
        }
        else print_r($error);
    }

?>

        <form method="post">

    <p>
            <label for="txtUsername">Enter Username</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername" placeholder="Username"/>
        </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="txtEmail">Enter Email</label>
    <div>
        <input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
    </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="txtPassword">Enter Password</label>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label>Enter Confirm Password</label>
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
    </div>
    </p>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Well, what are you entering for an email that would throw that kind of error?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `!` - `if ( ! is_email() )`

Comment: @SallyCJ thanks, you are right.

Comment: @SallyCJ I will similiar custom page for video upload.How can call my own variables from this page? Can you look at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/361055/custom-plugin-database-relations

Comment: @ExcaliburSword, I hope you don't mind I edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing the "not" operator (`!`) in my conditional (`if(is_email($email))`), which in turn resulted in valid email addresses being treated as invalid. So I added the `!` and that solved the problem:

```php
// code before; incorrect - missing the !
if(is_email($email)) {
    $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
}

// code after; working as expected after I added the !
if(! is_email($email)) { // if email is invalid, add the error message
    $error['email_valid'] = "Email has no valid value";
}
```